# same condition statement on multiple pages in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using next js in my project
when i fetch from my server using useswr hook then there is certain condition to return on the page for example

### dashboard.js

```js
import InnerNavbar from "../components/InnerNavbar";
import DashboardLoadingSkeleton from "../components/DashboardLoadingSkeleton";
import DashBoardData from "../components/DashBoardData";
import useSWR, { mutate } from "swr";

const fetcher = async () => await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/fetchchallenges`, {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: 'include'
}).then((res) => res.json());

const dashboard = () => {
    const { data, error } = useSWR("/dashboard", fetcher, { dedupingInterval: 40000 });
    if (!data) {
        if (!data.Errors) {
            return (<><InnerNavbar /><DashBoardData data={data} mutate={mutate} /></>);
        } else if (data.Errors === "Not Approved") {
            return (<>{location.replace('/notapproved')} <center><h1>Not Approved By Admin</h1></center></>)
        }else {
            return (<>{location.replace('/logout')} <center><h1>Redirecting...</h1></center></>)
        }
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                <InnerNavbar />
                <DashboardLoadingSkeleton />
            </>
        )
    }
};

export default dashboard;
```

now i want to need this same conditional statement in multiple pages to return but i don't known how to create a separate function for that.

Comment: You mean the entire `dashboard` reusable on other pages?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need to create a function that i call in passing the components and url and then function return jsx that i rendered on multiple pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [react Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

here is sth that I made:

```
import useSWR, { mutate } from "swr";

const fetcher = async () => await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/fetchchallenges`, {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: 'include'
}).then((res) => res.json());

const withSwrData = ({Component,endpoint}) => {
    const { data, error } = useSWR(endpoint, fetcher, { dedupingInterval: 40000 });
    if (!data) {
        if (!data.Errors) {
            return (<Component  data={data} mutate={mutate} />);
        } else if (data.Errors === "Not Approved") {
            return (<>{location.replace('/notapproved')} <center><h1>Not Approved By Admin</h1></center></>)
        }else {
            return (<>{location.replace('/logout')} <center><h1>Redirecting...</h1></center></>)
        }
    } else {
        return (
            <>
            <Component /> 
            </>
        )
    }
};

export default withSwrData;
```

and use it in dashboard in this way :

```
import InnerNavbar from "../components/InnerNavbar";
import DashboardLoadingSkeleton from "../components/DashboardLoadingSkeleton";
import DashBoardData from "../components/DashBoardData";
import withSwrData from "../withSwrData"

const dashboard = ({data,mutate}) => {


  return (<>
      <InnerNavbar />
      {data ? <DashBoardData data={data} mutate={mutate} /> : <DashboardLoadingSkeleton /> }
  </>)
};

export default withSwrData(dashboard,"/dashboard");
```